# where does msal-node store its tokens?

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

I am working on enabling SSO for one of our apps. I am using the NodeJS MSAL-node module. I am using the authorization code flow. It works fine but I don't see anything stored in cookies, local storage or session storage. My question is where does MSAL-node store its ID token, refresh token or access token to enable SSO?

Answer (score 2):

They are stored in the applications memory. You can retrieve them with getTokenCache().

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-node/docs/accounts.md

Cookies, local storage or session storage are in the browser. Since node does not run in the browser, the tokens are not there.